# How to make a Java Proxy/Cache File System (VFS)

Tags: java, caching, proxy, vfs

I want to cache network files local in a directory. The Cache should be persistent, read-only and should be capable of managing it size (maximum size of disk usage, deleting not used files when full). I looked into [Apache JVS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/), but I got more and more confused, how to use it (Cache/Replicator) or writing a new provider?

I started writing a custom Cache, but I'm not sure if I am on the right track. 
Another thing  is, that it is triggered at resolveFile not when accessing the InputStream.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new PlayCache().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        try {

            final StandardFileSystemManager fm = new StandardFileSystemManager();
            fm.setFilesCache(new WarpCache());
            fm.init();
            VFS.setManager(fm);

            final FileSystemManager fsm = VFS.getManager();


            final FileObject fo = fsm.resolveFile("/mnt/archive/someFile.tgz");
            final InputStream is = fo.getContent().getInputStream();

            long counter=0;
            while (is.read()!=-1)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println(counter);
            //  replicator.close();
            //dfsm.close();
        } catch (final FileSystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public class WarpCache extends AbstractFilesCache{

    private final FilesCache subCache;

    public WarpCache() {
        this(new SoftRefFilesCache());
    }

    public WarpCache(final FilesCache cache) {
        super();
        subCache = cache;
    }


    public void putFile(final FileObject file) {
        subCache.putFile(file);
    }

    public boolean putFileIfAbsent(final FileObject file) {
        return subCache.putFileIfAbsent(file);
    }

    public FileObject getFile(final FileSystem filesystem, final FileName name) {
        return subCache.getFile(filesystem, name);
    }

    public void clear(final FileSystem fileSystem) {
        subCache.clear(fileSystem);

    }

    public void removeFile(final FileSystem filesystem, final FileName name) {
        subCache.removeFile(filesystem, name);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a bit too broad for StackOverflow.  It would help if you could point to a specific problem with the code.  For something of this inherent complexity, "am I on the right track" could take an entire textbook to answer.  There's a quote/meme: _"The two hardest things in software engineering are cache coherency, naming things, and off-by-one errors"_

Comment: @JimGarrison Nice quote that is, I didnt know about that off by one error ;-)

Comment: @JimGarrison Great quote, I love it!
It would already help if someone can give me a link how to use replicator in vfs.